# Conflict on javascript form validation

Tags: javascript, validation

I have implemented a simple javascript validation but the validation and the form submission never happen together ...

When i use "onsubmit" (like below) it will goto the next page without validation

if i use "onclick" on the end of the form

```
<input type="button" name="submit" id="send" value="Search Flights" onclick="return validate_booking_form();" />
</form>
```

it will validate the input .. but the form wont be submitted even the correct input

This is the code i have used 
//Javascript Validation

```
function validate_booking_form()
{
    chk_fromcity();
    chk_tocity();
    chk_depature_date();                   

}

function chk_fromcity()
{
    var from_city = $('#from_cities').val();
    if (from_city == '')
    {
        $("#from_cities").removeClass('fieldInput');
        $("#from_cities").addClass('error');
        $("#errormsg_from").fadeTo(200, 1, function()
        {
            $(this).html('Please Enter a City').addClass('errormsg');                   
        })
    }
    else
    {
        $('#from_cities').removeClass('error'); 
        $('#from_cities').addClass('fieldInput');
        $("#errormsg_from").fadeTo(200, 1, function()
        {
            $(this).html('').removeClass('errormsg');                   
        })             
    } 
}
```

and the form

```
<form method="POST" action="../controller/booking.php" name="search_flights_names" onsubmit="return validate_booking_form();" >

    /// Form content 
<div class="form_input_container">
                        <div class="form_input">
     <input type="text" id="from_cities" name="from_city" class="fieldInput" onblur="return chk_fromcity()" /> 
                         </div>
</div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="send" value="Search Flights" />
</form>
```

Comment: And where is code for the function `validate_booking_form`?

Comment: Sorry ! I forgot to include that .....  code is edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submit is the proper button to use.

Try putton `onsubmit` in your form element and have the validation occur there instead of on the click event. That way pressing enter won't bypass all of your validation.

Comment: actually i used Submit button, in this case form will submit without the validation

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Jquery validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/). I think it should pretty much solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

return false from chk_fromcity() to stop the form posting to action.

```
function chk_fromcity()
{
    var from_city = $('#from_cities').val();
    if (from_city == '')
    {
        $("#from_cities").removeClass('fieldInput');
        $("#from_cities").addClass('error');
        $("#errormsg_from").fadeTo(200, 1, function()
        {
            $(this).html('Please Enter a City').addClass('errormsg');                   
        });

        return false;
    }

    $('#from_cities').removeClass('error'); 
    $('#from_cities').addClass('fieldInput');
    $("#errormsg_from").fadeTo(200, 1, function()
    {
        $(this).html('').removeClass('errormsg');                   
    })             

    // return  true; // default is true which is why you were passing the validation
}
```